# Filtering ngTable with a function

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4PkmPGk67sYvsNHmX4ro?p=preview) I have an ngTable with `show-filter=true`. One of the columns (Group Name) shows a string that's a function of another column (Group). The problem is that I cannot filter by Group Name as it is a "derived" column. How to filter by Group Name?

HTML:

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered" show-filter="true">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in $data">
                <td title="'User ID'" filter="{ uid: 'text' }">
                    {{ u.uid }}
                </td>
                <td title="'Name'"  filter="{ nm: 'text' }">
                  {{ u.nm }}
                </td>
                <td title="'Group ID'"  filter="{ ugr: 'text' }">
                   {{ u.ugr }}
                </td>
                <td title="'Group Name'"  filter="{ groupName(u.ugr): 'text' }">
                  {{ groupName(u.ugr) }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {

      $scope.data = [{
          uid: 'User 1',
          nm: 'Name 1',
          ugr: 1
      }, {
          uid: 'User 2',
          nm: 'Name 2',
          ugr: 2
      }, {
          uid: 'User 3',
          nm: 'Name 3',
          ugr: 2
      }];


      $scope.groupName = function(group){
          if (group==1)  
              return 'AAA';
          else
              return 'BBB';
      };


      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
          count: 5
      }, {
          data: $scope.data
      });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the grouping in the controller to save you the trouble.

I have used the map function to do the validation for setting the group value, then just show it as a normal text filter.

The map function is as follows

```
$scope.data = [{
          uid: 'User 1',
          nm: 'Name 1',
          ugr: 1
      }, {
          uid: 'User 2',
          nm: 'Name 2',
          ugr: 2
      }, {
          uid: 'User 3',
          nm: 'Name 3',
          ugr: 2
      }].map(function(x){x['group'] = x.ugr === 1 ? 'AAA' : 'BBB';return x;});
```

Below is a demo for the same, let me know if this helps you.

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>